# How to screen robocalls by forcing caller to press a certain key combination? (audio CAPTCHA)

Tags: call-screening

I am trying to stop all those junk calls I am getting, I have tried quite a few apps like Hiya, TrueCaller etc; unfortunately, phone numbers are easy to spoof and those apps can't screen all that spam

Allowing calls from my contact list only is not an option for now

**Question** - is there a way which will answer the call, **ask caller to press a certain keys** (playing message like "Press 4-5-6 to be connected) and disconnect the call if caller failed to do so? (audio CAPTCHA)

I have Android 7.1.1

Comment: Asking for apps is off topic here, so edited to avoid closure on these grounds. If you are keen on "app solution only " see - - - - > Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575).

Comment: Steve: Did you ever find a solution? I had the exact same idea as you did.

Comment: unfortunately, no solution yet ....

Comment: I am looking for the same thing.  I remember in the early 1990s someone told me they had a service where callers would hear a recording and have to punch in a certain code in order to ring through.  Otherwise, at best they could only leave a voice mail.  *And for this person, they would never even hear the phone ring if the caller didn't know the secret code*.  That would be awesome.  @SteveV - Any luck yet on finding anything like this?

Comment: A great CAPTCHA would be to tell the caller they have to type in the last four digits of the phone number from which they are calling.  If they can't match their own caller ID then they can't get through!